# Why do I get a "Call to a member function where() on a non-object" error?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have problem when I try to get elements from database if table is empty, I get this error

> Call to a member function where() on a non-object

If I insert data into table it will work fine

```
$projects = Project::find(Auth::user() -> id)->where('admin_id', Auth::id())->where('actived',0)->lists('name','id');
```

Any solution? :)

Answer (score 2):

the `find()` method on an Eloquent mode will retrieve a single instance of the model where the ID matches. Adding the `where()` condition doesn't make sense and, in your case, you're not finding a model which matches, so you're getting that error message because `Project::find()` is returning `null`.

If you want to query for single project which matches ALL the conditions you've listed, do it like this:

```
$projects = Project::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('admin_id', '=', Auth::id())
                ->where('actived', '=', 0)
                ->get();
```

Note that I've made some guesses here about what you're trying to accomplish - the column names above may not be correct.

This will give you a collection containing zero or more instances of the `Project` Eloquent model.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution just replaced `find` with `findOrNew`:

```
$projects = Project::findOrNew(Auth::user() -> id)->where('admin_id', Auth::id())->where('actived',0)->lists('name','id');
```